# How to push the Laravel job to the queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I have a class XYJob which was created by artisan command and implements the **ShouldQueue** class. 
The QUEUE_DRIVER=redis in the .env file.

**The problem is that when i dispatch the job, it runs as a simple php function. The queue listener is not running, but the job runs as a simple function.**

It is laravel 5.8 application with predis/predis: ^1.1.
I have tried to clear the **cache** and the **config**. I have tried to use composer dump-autoload.

```
namespace Modules\ModuleName\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class XYJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::info('Job is running');
    }
}
```

Laravel documentation says:

*The generated class will implement the ShouldQueue interface, indicating to Laravel that the job should be pushed onto the queue to run asynchronously.*

BUT my job is definitely running.

Comment: Can you share how you are dispatching your job?

Comment: XYJob::dispatch()->onQueue('custom-queue')

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5.8** application should has **QUEUE_CONNECTION** in the .env file.

Answer (score -1):

How are you dispatching the job? Have you followed the example on the Laravel doscs site at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dispatching-jobs i.e.

```
\App\Jobs\ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast);
```

or dispatch(new \App\Jobs\ProcessPodcast($podcast);

```
dispatch(new \App\Jobs\ProcessPodcast($podcast);
```

If the job is not dispatched in this manner (i.e. you're simply newing up the job class), it will not be pushed to the queue.